# How can I implement getting Web API data in an ASP.NET MVC app using the repository architecture?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, repository

I have the following code which can retrieve data from an ASP.NET Web API:

```
string BaseUrl = "https://localhost:48262/";

public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    List<User> users= new List<User>();

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage res = await client.GetAsync("api/Users");

        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var userdiagnosisRes = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            users = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<User>>(userRes);
        }

        return View(users);
    }
}
```

This code work, it's located in the controller and the data gets displayed on the `Index` page.

How can I implement this is a repository architecture? My app also has a `DbContext` connection with another database, but for this connection I have to retrieve data from a RESTapi. I want to be able to use the webapi data in other places than just this controller.

Answer (score 0):

I take advantage of delegates and expressions:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAsync(string url, Action<HttpRequestHeaders> headers, Action<IHttpRequestParameters> parameters)
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            headers?.Invoke(client.DefaultRequestHeaders);

            if (parameters != null)
            {
                parameters.Invoke(_httpRequestParameters);
                var query = _httpRequestParameters.GetQueryString();
                url += query;
            }

            return await client.GetAsync(url);
        }
    }
```

Then call it like this:

```
var test = await _handler.GetAsync("https://myurl.com", header =>
        {
            header.Add("mynewheader", "ha! it works!!");
            header.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));
            header.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "fefe5648564grgrgr65446");
        }, parameters =>
        {
            parameters.Add("test", "firstparam");
            parameters.Add("test2", "secondparam");
        });
```